# How to set ngIf dynamic condition in dynamic form in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I am creating a dynamic form where I am populating the fields dynamically based on the response from JSON like.

Eg:-

```
[{
  "type":"text",
  "required":true,
  "minlength": 3,
  "maxlength":5,
  "name":"fname",
  "visibility":true
},
{
  "type":"text",
  "required":true,
  "minlength": 3,
  "maxlength":5,
  "name":"lname",
  "visibility":"fname == 'abc' || fname == 'xyz'"
},
{
  "type":"text",
  "required":true,
  "minlength": 3,
  "maxlength":5,
  "name":"fid",
  "visibility":true
},
{
  "type":"text",
  "required":true,
  "minlength": 3,
  "maxlength":5,
  "name":"lid",
  "visibility":"fid == 1 || fid == 4"
}]
```

I have a usecase where the second field should be visible only when the first  field should have the values 'abc' or 'xyz'(Condition  is written in  the JSON property).How can that be achieved dynamically?

Comment: You could create your own directive `*ngIfVisibility` based on `*ngIf`

Comment: @Safiyya can you provide me some working example?

Comment: Nope I cannot, sorry I misread your post.

Comment: @SureshB, That's hard, also interesting question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `evaluation` method in component:

```
 isVisible(value){
    //console.log(eval(value));
    return eval(value); 
  }
```

And call it in template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible(question.visibility)">
        <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
        <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
            <input [name]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

            <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
    </div>
```

Your `json` file will be like:

```
 ...
 new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'firstName',
        label: 'First name',
        value: 'Bombasto',
        required: true,
        order: 1, 
        visibility: 'true'
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2,
        visibility: 'this.form.get("firstName").value ==="abc"'
      })
```

`visibility: 'this.form.get("firstName").value ==="abc"'`, as you can see you should write in `json` as usual in component class logic, because it will run in component context

[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-forms-with-conditions)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for