# How to check if selected dynamic form input meets some criteria

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm still relatively new to Angular and the logic of this nested JSON is getting the better of me, so I apologize.

I am looking to create a dynamic form and used [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/angular-dynamic-forms-ng-switch-approach-4f267c01d2c6) as a starting point.

I am trying to build out conditional fields that will only display if the user selects a certain option. I would like it to work so that if any of my options has children defined in an array, a subsequent input with those children as options appears. I still have a ton of things to consider, but right now I'm trying to get it so that when a user selects Option 2, Option 2A and Option 2B automatically appear in another dropdown underneath.

How can I create an ngIf* statement that says "if the currently selected option has children, add them to another input"?

[Here is my code in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-v6c5d)

I have tried checking that the array length of "children" is longer than zero, and also created a boolean called "hasChildren" and manually assigning a true/false value to check against (though I don't prefer this solution because the finished app will have many nested options and it would be easier to just check if the array is empty or not).

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527981/how-to-set-ngif-dynamic-condition-in-dynamic-form-in-angular-4) but must have had a syntax error, because it didn't work for me.

HTML:

```
<ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'select'">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label [for]="input.controlName"> {{input.controlName}}</label>
          <select [formControlName]="input.controlName" [name]="input.controlName" [id]="input.controlName"
          [required]="input.validators.required">
          <option value="">{{input.placeholder}}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let option of input.options" [value]="option.value">{{option.optionName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <div *ngIf="this.input.options.children > 0" class="form-group">
          <label [for]="input.options.optionName">{{input.options.optionName}}</label>
          <select [formOptionName]="input.options.children.childName" [name]="input.options.children.childName" [id]="input.options.children.childName">
          <option *ngFor="let children of input.options.children" [value]="children.value">{{children.childName}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

form-data.ts

```
export interface FormData {
  controlName: string;
  controlType: string;
  valueType?: string;
  currentValue?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  options?: Array<{
    optionName: string;
    value: string;
    hasChildren: boolean;
    children: Array<{
      childName: string;
      childValue: string;
    }>
  }>;
  validators?: {
    required?: boolean;
    minlength?: number;
    maxlength?: number;
  };
}
```

mock-form.ts

```
import { FormData } from './../interface/form-data';

export const MockForm: FormData[] = [
  {
    controlName: 'Options',
    placeholder: 'Choose an option',
    controlType: 'select',
    options: [{
      optionName: 'Option 1',
      value: 'option 1',
      hasChildren: false,
      children: []
      },
      {
      optionName: 'Option 2',
      value: 'option 2',
      hasChildren: true,
      children: [{
        childName: 'Option 2A',
        childValue: 'option 2a',
        },
        {
        childName: 'Option 2B',
        childValue: 'option 2b'
        }],
      }],
    validators: {
      required: true
    }
  }
]
```

I expect to get an output of a second dropdown containing options "Option 2A" and "Option 2B" when the user selects "Option 2," but I get a parsing error.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code please check: 
[Your updated code sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-mdys6?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you! This makes the syntax much easier to understand. It looks like I was missing an ngFor wrapper for the ngIf, which makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to make my code functional. I was noticing, however, that the current logic only works if the value "option 2" is selected from the dropdown. Is there a way to make it so that any item with children, regardless of name, will generate a secondary dropdown when chosen?

Comment: you can make it more dynamic but you will have to change the json object data in such a way that your childControll name and the parent option value must be same.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-mdys6?fontsize=14 
here i have changed the json object and compared the value dynamically. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[check this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/service-category)

I think you are looking for cascading dropdown. The above solution may help you check it.